# Hard time creating an Accordion using CSS or jQuery for Wordpress

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, menu, accordion

I need help creating an accordion menu. I can not edit the HTML code as it is being generated through a widget and a plugin. Whatever code I use, the Parent doesn't display Child and unable to inject font-awesome icons. I am trying to recreate something like this: [CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/duked/pen/xgmzqw?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=700fe7ffb29d1de44edd8642d4232bf380051479-1596422249-0-AXz9AQosDOj5hfMxTm9UrdxmRy9GnNBeAlGZyfrhfcKq-VJn87cufm39vC7I4-Pp7KvmvN9XCAlnAjD0-_QxAGH2uufc8j-3IAcre6yWibz1FfWfpF7YjStPIevLXT0bkj-lfjTP4UhdH0OL5-NgcnNwxmqKwDh594dG2HuBpX4hDAew8SfjuuKccNLvO3qkvtIaP9cHPe-stO-_cdra8Um-f4vVO7hK3Ku5sPO5hJFs7pD2I2_e9LLx79ZzIjeaN1_zNTUuTKraOGVfyQHdhnHeRXk6OsFPIFRBCLepZ2-h6ckHOENxzbudwReV2ztlHaSpMeH4jC539FAVPE9wR2LpTrcxAjxJHYr9kxoyNg0U) A simple accordion menu will work too if font-awesome icons are not possible.
The code I am working with:

```
<div class="categories_list">
<ul>
        <li class="parent_cat"><a class="" href="#">Show All</a></li>
            <li class="parent_cat"><a data-term_id="68" class="wcfm_tax_filter_toggle_parent  " href="#">ALCOPOPS &amp; PRE MIXED SPIRITS</a></li>
                <li class="child_cat wcfm_tax_filter_toggle_68"><a class="" href="#">PRE MIXED SPIRITS</a></li>
            <li class="parent_cat"><a data-term_id="69" class="filter_toggle_parent  " href="#">BABY &amp; TODDLER</a></li>
                    <li class="child_cat wcfm_custom_hide filter_toggle_69"><a class="" href="#">NAPPIES</a></li>
                    <li class="child_cat wcfm_custom_hide filter_toggle_69"><a class="" href="#">CHILDRENS MEDICINES</a></li>
                    <li class="child_cat wcfm_custom_hide filter_toggle_69"><a class="" href="#">BABY WIPES</a></li>
                    <li class="child_cat wcfm_custom_hide filter_toggle_69"><a class="" href="#">BABY TOILETRIES</a></li>
                    <li class="child_cat wcfm_custom_hide filter_toggle_69"><a class="" href="#">BABY FOOD &amp; MILK</a></li>
                    <li class="child_cat wcfm_custom_hide filter_toggle_69"><a class="" href="#">SOOTHERS, BOTTLES, STERILISERS</a></li>
            <li class="parent_cat"><a data-term_id="70" class="filter_toggle_parent  " href="#">BEER/LAGER</a></li>
                    <li class="child_cat wcfm_custom_hide filter_toggle_70"><a class="" href="#">LOW/NO ALCOHOL</a></li>
                    <li class="child_cat wcfm_custom_hide filter_toggle_70"><a class="" href="#">LAGER</a></li>
                    <li class="child_cat wcfm_custom_hide filter_toggle_70"><a class="" href="#">ALE &amp; STOUT</a></li>
            <li class="parent_cat"><a data-term_id="71" class="filter_toggle_parent  " href="#">BISCUITS</a></li>
                    <li class="child_cat wcfm_custom_hide filter_toggle_71"><a class="" href="#">SWEET BISCUITS</a></li>
                    <li class="child_cat wcfm_custom_hide filter_toggle_71"><a class="" href="#">CRACKERS &amp; SAVOURY BISCUITS</a></li>
            <li class="parent_cat"><a class="active" href="#">CARRIER BAGS &amp; OTHER WRAPPINGS</a></li>
            <li class="parent_cat"><a class="" href="#">CIDER</a></li>
            <li class="parent_cat"><a data-term_id="74" class="filter_toggle_parent  " href="#">CIGS CIGARS TOBACCO</a></li>
                    <li class="child_cat filter_toggle_74"><a class="" href="#">TOBACCO</a></li>
                    <li class="child_cat filter_toggle_74"><a class="" href="#">CIGARS</a></li>
                    <li class="child_cat filter_toggle_74"><a class="" href="#">CIGARETTES</a></li>
            <li class="parent_cat"><a data-term_id="75" class="filter_toggle_parent  " href="#">CONFECTIONERY</a></li>
                    <li class="child_cat wcfm_custom_hide filter_toggle_75"><a class="" href="#">SUGAR CONFECTIONERY</a></li>
                    <li class="child_cat wcfm_custom_hide filter_toggle_75"><a class="" href="#">MINTS/TIC TACs &amp; GUM</a></li>
                    <li class="child_cat wcfm_custom_hide filter_toggle_75"><a class="" href="#">CHOCOLATE CONFECTIONERY</a></li>
                    <li class="child_cat wcfm_custom_hide filter_toggle_75"><a class="" href="#">CEREAL BARS</a></li>
            <li class="parent_cat"><a data-term_id="76" class="filter_toggle_parent  " href="#">CRISPS &amp; SNACKS</a></li>
                    <li class="child_cat wcfm_custom_hide filter_toggle_76"><a class="" href="#">NUTS &amp; ADULT SNACKS</a></li>
                    li class="child_cat wcfm_custom_hide filter_toggle_76"><a class="" href="#">SNACKS</a></li>
                    <li class="child_cat wcfm_custom_hide filter_toggle_76"><a class="" href="#">POTATO CRISPS</a></li>
            <li class="parent_cat"><a data-term_id="91" class="filter_toggle_parent  " href="#">SPIRITS</a></li>
                    <li class="child_cat wcfm_custom_hide filter_toggle_91"><a class="" href="#">SCHNAPPS &amp; OTHER SPIRITS</a></li>
</ul>
    
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('.filter_toggle_parent').each(function() {
        $(this).off('click').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            
            $term_id = $(this).data('term_id');
            $('.filter_toggle_'+$term_id).toggleClass( 'custom_hide' );
            
            return false;
        });
      });
    });
    </script>
    </div>
```

Yep, it's generating Child list dynamically through js within the code and toggle to show it.

All the help will be highly appritiated. Thanks!

Comment: there is alot of example you can search in google

Comment: so this not technical example

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Of course, I have been trying everything from google but I must be missing something and unable to do it. The reason for posting it here.